# Why is my Cat palm drooping?

Tags: houseplants, palm

[image]My cat palm is dropping and I don’t know why, I did have mites but I cleaned it off and  have continued to care for it. I have followed all the advice given on it. How long can it take to recover from mites?

Comment: I can't tell from the photo, does the pot has drain holes? Cat palms love water, but not muddy or soggy soil; that can be difficult to achieve without drain holes. How long have you had the palm? How long in that location? Have you changed the watering regimen lately?